# Angular 16.2.0 Signal TypeError <mySignal> is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-signals

I've a service with a signal owning a list of Customers (interface).
When I call a method that get the signal content, an issue is raised:

> ERROR TypeError: this.customers is not a function at Object.upsertCustomer [as next]

Below the source code:

```
//interfaces
export interface CustomerProxy {
    id?: number,
    name: string,
    category: string,
    phone?: string,
    mobile?: string,
    email?: string,
}

export interface Customer extends CustomerProxy {
    vat_number?: string,
    address?: string,
}
//declaration
customers = signal<CustomerProxy[]>([])
//API
onUpdateCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
    console.log('onUpdateCustomer')
    return this.httpClient.put<Customer>(`${this.url}/${customer.id}`, customer)
      .pipe(
        tap(this.upsertCustomer),
        //catchError(this.handleError),
      )
  }
//Inner method
private upsertCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    console.log('upsertCustomer')
    const index = this.customers().findIndex(item => item.id === customer.id) //this line raises the error
    if (index === -1) {
      // Not in list -> add
      this.customers.mutate(customers => [...customers, customer as CustomerProxy])
    } else {
      // Already in the list, update
      this.customers.mutate(customers => customers[index] = customer as CustomerProxy)
    }
  }
```

I don't understand how to fix the issue.

**Dependencies**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.upsertCustomer` is likely undefined in the [runtime context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#description).

Use an arrow function to maintain the `this` context :

```
tap(() => this.upsertCustomer),
```

Answer (score 1):

refer below example

**service**

```
private cars$ = this.http.get<Car[]>(this.url).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

**component**

```
  cars = computed(() => {
    try {
      return this.carService.cars();
    } catch (e) {
      this.errorMessage = typeof e === 'string' ? e : 'Error';
      return [];
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code. it should resolve the error you were encountering:

```
private upsertCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    console.log('upsertCustomer');
    
    // Access the array of customers using this.customers.value
    const customersArray = this.customers.value;
    
    const index = customersArray.findIndex(item => item.id === customer.id);
    
    if (index === -1) {
        // Not in the list -> add
        this.customers.mutate(customers => [...customers, customer as CustomerProxy]);
    } else {
        // Already in the list, update
        this.customers.mutate(customers => {
            customers[index] = customer as CustomerProxy;
            return [...customers];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Customers is a [Signal](https://angular.io/guide/signals). The only way to access the data owned by the signal is via `()`. The `.value` notation doesn't exist. However I've tried to assign to a constant the signal value and then I've tried to work with that but I use to get always the same issue at constant declaration.